# Apache Wildcard Directory Use Alias File

Tags: apache-2.4

I am trying to achieve the following:

All searches at `https://example.com/a/*` will display file `article.php`.

For example (links to articles):

```
https://example.com/a/new-robot-eats-banana 
https://example.com/a/best-shoes-for-mud
https://example.com/a/its-about-time-we-move-to-mars
```

Will use `article.php`

```
echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
```

*Example:*

```
https://example.com/a/new-robot-eats-banana

new-robot-eats-banana
```

While keeping the url the same.

Is this done using `alias`?

```
Alias /a/* article.php
```

Comment: see: [Apache rewrite URL if accessed in specific directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/94736/apache-rewrite-url-if-accessed-in-specific-directory)

Comment: Have you tried something like `<Location /a>FallbackResource /path/to/article.php</Location>` Note this path starts from documentroot not from root filesystem.